# Logback custom appender to push logs to ElasticSearch via Open Telemetry

Tags: java, elasticsearch, apache-nifi, logback, open-telemetry

I am using apache Nifi , which uses logback framework for logging.
I have written a custom log appender to push logs to MongoDB.
Now I have a requirement to push logs in specific format (json) to ElasticSearch.

As few other apps are already using open telemetry to push data to ES, i have been asked to do so.

So now I am looking for right way to push data from my custom log appender (java class) to Open Telemetry.

Could some please point me to the usefull example which I can refer ?

Mongo appender looks like below, same message I want to push Open Telemetry also.

```
@Override
public void start() {
    super.start();
    logger.info("Initialising MongoDBLogAppender ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
    try{
        createConnection();
    }catch (Exception e){
        logger.error("Failed to obtain a database instance from the MongoClient at server [{}] and port [{}].", this.server, this.port);
    }
}

private MongoClient createConnection () throws Exception {
    if (client == null)
    {
        client = createMongoClient(this.server, this.port, this.databaseName, this.userName, this.password);
    }

    if (this.databaseName != null && (!"".equals(this.databaseName))) {
        database = client.getDatabase(this.databaseName);
    } else {
        logger.error("Mongo database name is required.");
    }
    return client;
}


@Override
protected void append(ILoggingEvent iLoggingEvent) {
    if (database == null)
        return;

    String logMessage = iLoggingEvent.getMessage() == null ? "" : iLoggingEvent.getMessage();
    logger.info("LogMessage (inside append method) : "+logMessage);//Change the level to debug after testing

    String[] msgParts = parseLogMessage(logMessage);
    Document doc = new Document()
            .append("Timestamp", new Date(iLoggingEvent.getTimeStamp()))
            .append("Ip", this.hostIp)
            .append("Server", "NiFi")
            .append("Instance", "")
            .append("Url", "")
            .append("TTId", msgParts[1])
            .append("LTId", msgParts[0])
            .append("LUId", msgParts[2])
            .append("SId", msgParts[4])
            .append("RId", msgParts[3])
            .append("Level", iLoggingEvent.getLevel().levelStr)
            .append("Logger", iLoggingEvent.getLoggerName())
            .append("Thread", iLoggingEvent.getThreadName())
            .append("Message", msgParts[5])
            .append("Exception", iLoggingEvent.getThrowableProxy() != null ? ThrowableProxyUtil.asString(iLoggingEvent.getThrowableProxy()) : null);
    try
    {
        Publisher<InsertOneResult> publisher = database.getCollection(collectionName).insertOne(doc);
        publisher.subscribe(new Subscriber<InsertOneResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(final Subscription s) {
                s.request(1);  // <--- Data requested and the insertion will now occur
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(final InsertOneResult result) {}

            @Override
            public void onError(final Throwable t) {
                logger.error("Failed to insert Nifi log to mongodb : "+this.toString(),t);
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {}
        });
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        logger.error("Encountered exception while logging Nifi log to MongoDB : "+this.toString(), e);
    }
}


/* Log message format expected : "~(<LoggedinTenantId>, <TargetTenantId>, <Userid>) ~ <RequestId> ~ <SessionId> ~ <DetailedMessage>" */
public static String[] parseLogMessage(String logMessage){
    String[] msgParts = new String[6];
    ..................................
    return msgParts;
}


private synchronized static MongoClient createMongoClient(String server, int port, String databaseName, String userName, String password)
{
    ...................................
    return MongoClients.create(settings);
}
```

}

Thanks
Mahendra

Comment: Hi MHegde, you can swap out the call you make to MongoDB, with a call to the Open Telemetry. If you can share your MongoDB appender code, I can point out what needs to be changed.

Comment: @VijayKumar - Thanks Vijay, I have updated the question with mongo code part

Comment: One of the things you can do is, just use a file appender and provide that file path in the filelogreceiver's config inside opentelemetry-collector-contrib config and use and elasticsearch exporter. So, your pipeline would use fileloadreceiver as your receiver and elasticsearch exporter along with any processor you might want to use (e.g., batch etc.)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to write a logback appender. Checkout the [OpenTelemetry logback appender](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/tree/main/instrumentation/logback/logback-appender-1.0/library), which bridges logback logs into the OpenTelemetry log sdk. You can configure the OpenTelemetry log SDK to export the records to elastic search.